# c# XmlReader with base64 innertext

Tags: c#, xml, byte, xmlreader

Ok here is my problem. 
I am trying to take a screenshot, add it to an xmldocument, send it over a socket, and read it with a XmlReader.

Here's some code...

Server Side

```
private void SendRandomData(object data)
{
    XMLShitSock sock = data as XMLShitSock;
    if(sock != null)
    {
        int incnum = 0;
        while(sock.Connected)
        {
            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            XmlNode docNode = doc.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0", "UTF-8", null);
            doc.AppendChild(docNode);

            XmlNode productsNode = doc.CreateElement("image");

            productsNode.InnerText = Convert.ToBase64String(Program.CaptureImageToBytes(new Point(0, 0), new Rectangle(0, 0, Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Width, Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Height), ImageFormat.Png));
            doc.AppendChild(productsNode);
            string s = XMLShitSock.GetXmlString(doc);
            doc.Save("temp.xml");
            sock.WriteXMLMessage(doc);
            incnum++;
            Thread.Sleep(5000);
        }
    }
}
```

sock.WriteXMLMessage

```
public bool WriteXMLMessage(XmlDocument doc)
{
    try
    {
        ShittySocket.Client.Send(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(GetXmlString(doc)));
        return true;
    }
    catch(SocketException se)
    {
        this.Close();
        return false;
    }
}
```

To Read input

```
private void doInput()
{
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
    NetworkStream ns = new NetworkStream(ShittySocket.Client, false);
    while(_connected)
    {
        if(ns.DataAvailable)
        {
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(ns);
            char[] b = new char[512];
            int nread = sr.Read(b, 0, 512);

            ms.Write(System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(b, 0, nread), 0, nread);
            ms.Seek(0, System.IO.SeekOrigin.Begin);

            XmlReaderSettings xrs = new XmlReaderSettings();

            XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(ms);
            if(reader.Read())
            {
                XmlDocument objXmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
                objXmlDocument.Load(reader);
                onInput(this, objXmlDocument);
                ms.Close();
                ms = new MemoryStream();
            }
        }
        Thread.Sleep(100);
    }
}
```

Problem I'm having is I get an error in doInput() saying the end of the document was reached without find the  tag. I saved the xml file and looked through it and it exists, and I didn't even find any < characters besides those in the actual tags, so I'm not sure what's going on here. I'm obviously missing something.

Also, if you have concerns with the semantics or coding style, or anything that doesn't actually answer the question, please leave it as a comment, since it's not an answer.

Also
I've look through this ->> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmltextreader.readbase64.aspx and I'm hoping that there is a better way to deal with base64 data than separating it from the XMLDocument itself. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're assuming the entire data will be read in one 512-byte chunk. Therefore, if the actual data is, say, 513 bytes long then you won't get the closing angle bracket > at the end of the document, thus the XML parser fails.

I don't know exactly what type of network stream you're using but if it's plain vanilla sockets then you need some kind of delimiter to know when you've reached the end of one "send" and the start of the next, because vanilla sockets are just a pipeline of data. With one read you could be receiving half, one, two, three-and-a-bit actual blocks.

Handily, you have a delimiter in the form of the closing tag.

Comment: bah, the point was to append data until the reader.Read() returned true, which I assumed signified a finished xml document

Comment: Isn't there some way to validate that the xml document is complete? If there isn't there is no point in me using an XmlReader, as I would have to manually parse the data anyway, unless i'm missing something.

Comment: I could be wrong here but I would assume that the XmlReader expects all the data it needs to be there *before* it starts reading. Yours is not an unreasonable expectation, I must admit!

Comment: Agreed. It seems silly that we don't have a protocol that is as usable as tcpip that's packet based. I mean how often do you use Sockets as a stream(besides telnet and ssh). 99% of the time you have to delemit or specify the size of the data, why not make that the norm.

Answer (score 1):

Two things regarding `doInput()`:

1. `XmlReaderSettings xrs = new XmlReaderSettings();` is not needed since you don't use it in subsequent `XmlReader.Create()`. And there would be no need to unless you set some properties of it first.
2. You can't assume that `reader.Read()` read the whole xml right there. With `XmlReader` you have to do `Read()` until you get `false` in response.

It's also a good idea to `using(var reader = XmlReader.Create(...)) { ... }` so everything is nicely wrapped up when it's done reading.

Comment: First comment wasn't really an awnser, but the second seems to say that I have my idea of Read() backwards. So essentially the fix would be to change it to if(!reader.Read())?

Comment: @keton52: You have to do `while(reader.Read())`. In other words, you're done reading once you're out of that loop.

Comment: That doesn't make any sense with my code above. That would still give me errors.

Comment: I'm sorry. What I'm trying to say, you can't use your code the way it is. You have to first read the whole document using the loop. Or process those elements **as** you read them.

Comment: Yeah I understand that, I'm looking for a way to decide when it's time to take what I've gathered and turn it into an XMLDocument.

Comment: Ok so think of it like this, you've helped me realize that reader.Read() returns false when there are no more nodes to read. That's great, but what if I receive back to back xmldocuments, wouldn't I not get a false until the end of the second one? If that happens I'd get an error when trying to convert it into a single xmldocument. Is there a way to seperate them without manually parsing them?

Comment: @kelton52: Not sure there is a way, you'll have to figure out what's coming as you receive it. On previous point, how to build xml while receiving it, maybe a look at `XmlWriter.WriteNode(XmlReader...)` would help. In other words, while you `XmlReader.Read()` you're building an xml right here until the reading is done.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
ms.Position = 0;
```

instead of

```
ms.Seek(0, System.IO.SeekOrigin.Begin);
```

in `doInput()`

also you can try to replace

```
Encoding.ASCII
```

with

```
Encoding.UTF8
```

or just replace a lot of code with just:

```
    private void doInput()
    {
        NetworkStream ns = new NetworkStream(ShittySocket.Client, false);
        while (_connected)
        {
            if (ns.DataAvailable)
            {
                using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(ns, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8))
                {
                        XmlDocument objXmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
                        objXmlDocument.LoadXml(sr.ReadToEnd());
                        onInput(this, objXmlDocument);
                }
            }
            Thread.Sleep(100);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I could use sr.ReadToEnd(), but what happens when it processes a Read command and doesn't have all the data. TcpIp sockets don't send in packets, so wouldn't I get a half document that produces and error?

Comment: Also if I read to the end of the stream, wouldn't that just read and read until the connection is closed, since the end of a NetworkStream means it's closed?

Comment: I get it now. So, you simply read first 512 bytes and then create xml document out of it? Still don't get it :)

Comment: bah, the point was to append data until the reader.Read() returned true, which I assumed signified a finished xml document

Comment: I want to be sending multiple xmldocuments via one connection.

Comment: but that is honestly not, what is written in the code. as GeoffM suggested.

Comment: @Kelton52, yes, you're reading a bottomless bucket and you need to search the returned data to see if there is an entire block of data that you're interested in - in this case an XML document. But there may be the start of another in the same packet, or the end of one document and the start of the next. As a sender I could write 12345 but as receiver it may come as 12, then 34, then 5. Or 123, 4, then 5.

Comment: I understand that completely, the only reason I'm using XmlReader was I assumed it had some built in mechanism to handle that. Actually the only reason I'm sending data in XML is because I assumed it had that mechanism.

Comment: Hmm, if that's the only reason you're using XML then I'd suggest a vanilla stream with a single NON-base-64 character to delimit your screenshots. Theoretically you can skip encoding with vanilla sockets but that makes your delimiter more difficult (escape strings for starters). Alternatively, again with plain sockets, write a string denoting the length that follows, then throw the screenshot data immediately behind. At the other end you read the length text and *then* you can expect the specified number of characters.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't buy the fact that there is no built in mechanisms that could help. I've used "Plain" sockets a lot, and I just can't help but think there is a better way I just haven't found yet.

Comment: By the way, just read my comment. It reads as if I'm irritated, I'm not. Don't want to come of as a jerk, I appreciate your help.

Comment: No problem. You're probably just using it in an unusual way! FWIW I had to write something similar, albeit in Delphi, with the same issues.

Comment: There may well be a C# solution that I don't know of, or a 3rd party component, but the latter could well come with too much baggage for what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I've came up with a solution.
Here's the function

```
public static XmlDocument GrabXmlDocFromStream(StreamReader reader)
{
    using(MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        byte b = 0;
        while(!reader.EndOfStream)
        {
            b = (byte)reader.Read();
            ms.WriteByte(b);
            ms.Seek(0, System.IO.SeekOrigin.Begin);

            using(XmlReader xmlreader = XmlReader.Create(ms))
            {
                XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
                try
                {
                    if(Encoding.ASCII.GetChars(new byte[1] { b })[0] == '>')
                    {
                        if(xmlreader.Read())
                        {
                            XmlDocument objXmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
                            objXmlDocument.Load(xmlreader);
                            return objXmlDocument;
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch(XmlException xe) { }
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

You use it like this

```
            using(NetworkStream ns = new NetworkStream(ShittySocket.Client, false))
{
            using(StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(ns))
            {
                XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument();
                while(xdoc != null)
                {
                    xdoc = Program.GrabXmlDocFromStream(sr);
                    if(xdoc != null)
                        Program.Handle_Document(xdoc);
                }
            }
}
```

Here are the other two function mentioned in the code

```
    public static string GetXmlString(XmlDocument doc)
    {
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        XmlTextWriter xw = new XmlTextWriter(sw);
        doc.WriteTo(xw);
        return sw.ToString();
    }

    public static void Handle_Document(XmlDocument doc)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(GetXmlString(doc));
    }
```

This probably isn't the best solution, but I used the line if(Encoding.ASCII.GetChars(new byte[1] { b })[0] == '>') so that I don't get an exception every character. From what I understand using try-catch in this manner isn't exactly the "right" way to solve problems, but it works, and I think I can suffer the minor time penalty involved.
Any ideas would be nice, if you see something wrong with this let me know. Thanks.

Comment: After toying with it I think it's probably overkill :p. Works, but it relies on try/catches for verification, which is a bit sloppy.